# ThrowIfCancellationRequested with and without async/await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, .net-4.5

I have the following code that runs without throwing an exception:

```
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongRunningMethod(cancellationToken, progress), cancellationToken);
        t.ContinueWith(Callback, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Inside 'LongRunningMethod', I call cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(). The callback will always get called (which is what I want), and the Task that gets passed to the callback correctly has IsCancelled set to true or false.

Using the async/await keywords, I have to modify the above lines to the following:

```
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongRunningMethod(cancellationToken, progress), cancellationToken);
            textEdit1.Text =  "Done";
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            textEdit1.Text = "Cancelled";
        }
```

Why, in this case, does the ThrowIfCancellationRequested() throw an actual exception that I need to catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ContinueWith`, you're given the `Task` that was previously run and you can ask it if it cancelled or not (`Task.IsCancelled`).  With `await`, you don't have that.  The only way to communicate cancel is through the exception.

Now, `await` is simply uses Tasks, so you can "interject" with a continuation. For example:

```
await Task.Factory
  .StartNew(() => LongRunningMethod(cancellationToken, progress), cancellationToken)
  .ContinueWith(t=>Trace.WriteLine("Canceled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

You can still use await and then use `ContinueWith` to handle *only* the cancellation scenario.  so, technically the `await` is awaiting on the continuation.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. However, that leads to the following question - 'Task.Factory.StartNew' returns a Task, so why doesn't 'await Task.Factory.StartNew' also return a task that i could check the cancelled status of?

Comment: Probably to keep the syntax fairly clean.  async/await isn't the end-all-be-all of asynchronous syntax either.  It fits a specific niche of asynchronous programming: mostly to keep long operations off the UI thread to keep the UI thread responsive. But, I've updated by answer to show a hybrid of `await` and `Task`

Comment: Now, I'm finding that using ThrowIsCancellationIsRequested throws an exception instead of invoking a continuation in VS 2012... FWIW

Answer (score 2):

`async` was designed to make asynchronous code easier, and as much as possible like the equivalent synchronous code.

First off, note that there was always an exception being thrown. `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` will (surprise) *throw an exception* if cancellation has been requested.

In your existing code, this exception is caught and then placed on the `Task` (wrapped in an `AggregateException`). The `Task` interprets this condition as being "canceled". Then you can just check the boolean flag in your continuation.

But consider the equivalent synchronous code:

```
try
{
  LongRunningMethod(cancellationToken, progress);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
}
```

And that looks a lot like the `async` approach. Even if you use `ContinueWith`, there is still an exception that is thrown and being caught - logically, you are doing a `try`/`catch`. Personally, I prefer the explicit `try`/`catch` because:

- The intent is clearer, so the code is easier to read and maintain.
- The code is more accessible (the vast majority of C# programmers understand `try`/`catch`; a relative minority understand `ContinueWith`).

However, `ContinueWith` is (slightly) more efficient.